# XmlObject.selectPath() is generating the wrong Namespace prefix

Tags: xml, xsd, xmlbeans

Hello i need your help by the following Problem:

I have an XSD File with the followed Namespace:

```
xmlns="rrn:org.xcbl:schemas/xcbl/v3_5/xcbl35.xsd" targetNamespace="rrn:org.xcbl:schemas/xcbl/v3_5/xcbl35.xsd"
```

My Xml File Namespace is as followed:

```
<Order xmlns="rrn:org.xcbl:schemas/xcbl/v3_5/xcbl35.xsd">
```

I read the XML File and put the XML in an XmlObject. Now im using selectPath("./*") on that XmlObject. The Function generates the wrong Namespace Prefix.

```
<xml-fragment xmlns:xcb="rrn:org.xcbl:schemas/xcbl/v3_5/xcbl35.xsd">
```

Can you help me?

Answer (score 0):

There's nothing wrong with namespace prefix being generated.

Namespace prefix names themselves are insignificant; it is only through their binding to a namespace value that they derive meaning.

No conformant XML processor cares about the specific namespace prefix being used, and neither should you -- it's only the namespace value that matters.